# Groovy: Converting a string to integer gives NumberFormatException

Tags: string, groovy, int

I am trying to get a date from this text:

> {InstantSeconds=1581504140},ISO,Europe/Paris resolved to 2020-02-12T11:42:20

I tried doing

```
def text = "{InstantSeconds=1581504140},ISO,Europe/Paris resolved to 2020-02-12T11:42:20"
text = text.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "")
text = text.substring(10)
println "${text}"

int result= Integer.parseInt("${text}");
println result
```

But I'm getting

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "20200212114220"

I'm using this (for practice) https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/

Does anyone know why that happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value is too long for an integer. Use a Long datatype:

```
Long result = text.toLong()
assert result.class.name == 'java.lang.Long'
assert result == 20200212114220
```